# Split string in ruby when character is different to previous character

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I would like to split a string when a character changes.

For example `"aabbbc226%%*"` should be split into an array like this `["aa",  "bbb",  "c",  "22",  "6",  "%%",  "*"]`

Heres what I have right now

```
def split_when_char_change(str)
   array = Array.new
   chars = str.split('')
   chars.each { |c|
     array.push c
   }
   array
end
```

split_when_char_change("aabbbc226%%*")

I am getting this output: `["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "2", "2", "6", "%", "%", "*"]` which is wrong.

How can I get my desired array?

Comment: @sawa I made the question more explcit 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one liner using **[chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)**, **[map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)** and **[join](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Array.html#method-i-join)**:

```
"aabbbc226%%*".chars.chunk(&:itself).map{|_,c| c.join}
# => ["aa", "bbb", "c", "22", "6", "%%", "*"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"aabbbc226%%*".scan(/((.)\2*)/).to_h.keys
# => ["aa", "bbb", "c", "22", "6", "%%", "*"]
```

or

```
"aabbbc226%%*".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first)
# => ["aa", "bbb", "c", "22", "6", "%%", "*"]
```